# Quisiera que el nav bar en position sticky top 0 NO pase por debajo de los elementos, no puedo arreglar ese problema

Tags: html, css

Aqui esta el codigo HTML, como explique antes el problema es cuando pongo position sticky top 0 a mi nav, cuando lo hago inmediatamente se desordena todo o simplemente funciona pero pasar por DEBAJO de los elementos de la pagina y el hover tampoco funciona. El nav bar lo necesito en sticky top 0 sin que tenga fallas como las ya mencionadas. Como se arreglaria?
Tambien pondre el codigo CSS abajo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilosborrados.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bad+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bacasime+Antique&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bacasime+Antique&family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Ojeda</title>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url(images1/modern-white-background-free-vector.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: 100% 100%; background-attachment: fixed;">

<div class="header">

    <div class="contenedor">
        <nav>
            <img src="images1/logo.png" class="logo">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a href="nosotros.html">Quienes somos</a></li>
              <li><a href="portafolio.html">Portafolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="servicios.html">Servicios</a></li>
              <li><a href="testimonios.html">Testimonios</a></li>
              <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <div class="iconosocial">
        
                <ul>
        
                <li><a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        
                <li><a href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                </a></li>
        
                </ul>
                </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
    

<video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="video">
   <source src="images1/videoojeda.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<h1>
   <span style="--i:1;">O</span>
   <span style="--i:2;">J</span>
   <span style="--i:3;">E</span>
   <span style="--i:4;">D</span>
   <span style="--i:5;">A</span>
   <span style="--i:6;margin-left: 5vw;">M</span>
   <span style="--i:7;">A</span>
   <span style="--i:8;">R</span>
   <span style="--i:9;">K</span>
   <span style="--i:10;">E</span>
   <span style="--i:11;">T</span>
</h1>

</div>

    <div class="texto-debajo">
         <p>Un mercado que se dedica a la venta de diversos productos de consumo inmediato y de primera necesidad para satisfacer la necesidad de los clientes. <br> 
           Los proveedores son confiables y se dedican a traer productos de marcas conocidas para garantizar la calidad de todos los productos y así también vender una gran cantidad de productos. El objetivo de la empresa <br>
           es brindar experiencia de compra conveniente y agradable en un ambiente acogedor. Se esfuerza por superar las expectativas de los clientes y establecer relaciones duraderas basadas en la confianza y la satisfacción.</p>
    </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h3>Portafolio</h3>

    <div class="slider">
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria1.jpg);"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria2.jpg);"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria3.jpg);"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria4.jpg);"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria5.jpg);"></div>
    </div>
```

Aqui esta el codigo CSS, he cambiado el 'contenedor' y  pero sigue pasando los problemas que menciono. Los demas estilos que ven en el css son de otros elementos fuera del header y nav.

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(250, 252, 250), #5b5f5a);
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 98%;
    height: 85px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 1%;
    padding: 3px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
}


nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(168, 45, 45);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

li a:hover{

    color: rgb(250, 244, 238);
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .video {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .video {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}


i{
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

.iconosocial {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%;
    left: 82%;
    text-align: center;
}

.iconosocial ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    left: 91%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
}

.iconosocial ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.iconosocial ul li .fab {

    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 60px;
    transition: .3s;
    color: black;
}
.iconosocial ul li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.iconosocial ul li a{
    
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 41px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-right: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 243, 243);
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0.1);
    transition: .6s;
}
.iconosocial a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 35px; 
}

.iconosocial :nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(12, 35, 243);
}
.iconosocial :nth-child(2) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(243, 12, 185);

}
.iconosocial :nth-child(3) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(18, 175, 238);

}

.texto-debajo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.texto-debajo{
    background-image: linear-gradient(orange, rgb(128, 89, 18));
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
.texto-debajo p {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
}


h1 {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Bad Script', cursive;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 6vw;
    color: transparent;
}


h1 span {
    animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}
@keyframes animate {
    0%
    {
       color: white; 
       filter: blur(2px) hue-rotate(0deg);
       text-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow,  0 0 20px rgb(17, 90, 50),  0 0 40px rgb(12, 85, 24), 0 0 80px yellow,
       0 0 120px yellow,  0 0 200px yellow,  0 0 300px yellow,  0 0 400px yellow;
    }
    30%, 70%
    {
       color: white; 
       filter: blur(2px) hue-rotate(360deg);
       text-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow,  0 0 20px yellow,  0 0 40px yellow, 0 0 80px yellow,
       0 0 120px yellow,  0 0 200px yellow,  0 0 300px yellow,  0 0 400px yellow;
    }
    100% 
    {
        color: transparent;
        box-shadow: none;
        filter: blur(2px) hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}

h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
    height: 20rem;
    gap: 5px;
}

.slider div {
    flex: 1;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.25, .4, .45, 1.4);
}
.slider div:hover {
    flex: 5;
}


.contenedor4 {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 400px;
    align-items: center;
}

.contenedor4 img {

    height: 50px;
}

p{
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.text-container {
    background-color: rgb(218, 162, 11);
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    width: 650px;
    border-radius: 25% 10%;
}

.text-container2 {
    background-color: rgb(218, 162, 11);
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    width: 650px;
    border-radius: 25% 10%;
}

.containerT {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Si me podrían dar una breve explicación de como resolverlo lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y en el editor de texto hay un icono `<>`, lo presionas e introduce tu código donde corresponda. Además explica tu problema correctamente cosa que entendamos lo que quieres lograr, porque tal y como está tu pregunta `cuando pongo position sticky top 0 no funciona` la respuesta es `NO coloques sticky top 0` lo cual supongo que no es la respuesta que buscas.

Comment: Si muchas gracias, es mi primera vez usando esta pagina. Debi formular mejor la pregunta.

Comment: Queres que el navbar este siempre posicionado arriba de todo independientemente del scroll? aclárame el comportamiento que esperas del nav, porque quizas te convenga usar position: fixed en lugar de sticky

Comment: quisiera que el navbar siempre se posicione arriba de la pantalla mientras scrolleo para abajo. Haci como stackoverflow tiene la barra de navegacion fija arriba y cuando scrolleas para abajo, baja tambien cuando scrolleas. Por eso trataba de usar sticky top 0 para no tener que scrollear hasta arriba de nuevo si quisiera usar el navbar.

Comment: el problema es que aun asi consiga hacerlo, cuando scrolleo para abajo, el navbar pasa por detras de todo. Cuando deberia ser al revés. Deberia pasar por encima de todo.

Comment: Si ya encontraste una forma de resolver tu problema, no olvides colocarlo como respuesta, y de [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te fue más útil (si es la tuya, aguarda a que transcurra el tiempo mínimo para aceptarla).

Answer (score 0):

> No estoy 100% seguro de cuál es el resultado final que se espera.

Si lo que se quiere es que el nav sea sticky y se quede arriba de la página todo el tiempo aunque hagamos scroll, se puede comenzar por hacer que el header no tome un height de 100vh dejando la clase de esta forma:

```css
.header {  
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
```

Ya que si le damos el alto de toda la página, al hacer el scroll el header aparentaría que se queda arriba.

Adicionalmente es ideal poner las tags html correspondientes al elemento que se está mostrando. En este caso en vez de colocar un `<div class="header">` lo correcto sería colocar un tag `<header>` directamente para tener un html mas semántico y legible.

Otra cosa que causa este detalle es que al sticky se lo está poniendo dentro del nav y el nav tiene muchos nodos padre como el `<div class="container">` que desde mi perspectiva no son necesarios.

Por último, para tener un contenido más organizado, es ideal separar cada parte del sitio por secciones para lo cual se utiliza la tag `<section>` y con esto el contenido queda más organizado y limpio.

Respecto a que el contenido pasa por debajo de los elementos podría ser el z-index que se tiene en el apartado donde está el `<video>`, no pude probar eso, pero dejo un ejemplo con las correcciones ya mencionadas (aclarando que no estoy seguro si es el resultado que se espera) y también mencionar que el html que se proporcionó está incompleto.

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(250, 252, 250), #5b5f5a);
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 98%;
    height: 85px;
     position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 1%;
    padding: 3px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

nav .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
}


nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(168, 45, 45);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

li a:hover {

    color: rgb(250, 244, 238);
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .video {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .video {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}


i {
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

.iconosocial {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%;
    left: 82%;
    text-align: center;
}

.iconosocial ul {
    /* position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    left: 91%; */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
}

.iconosocial ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.iconosocial ul li .fab {

    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 60px;
    transition: .3s;
    color: black;
}

.iconosocial ul li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.iconosocial ul li a {

    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 41px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-right: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 243, 243);
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: .6s;
}

.iconosocial a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 35px;
}

.iconosocial :nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(12, 35, 243);
}

.iconosocial :nth-child(2) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(243, 12, 185);

}

.iconosocial :nth-child(3) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(18, 175, 238);

}

.texto-debajo {
    background-image: linear-gradient(orange, rgb(128, 89, 18));
    border-radius: 30px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: -1;
}

.texto-debajo p {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
}


h1 {
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Bad Script', cursive;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 6vw;
    color: transparent;
}


h1 span {
    animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        color: white;
        filter: blur(2px) hue-rotate(0deg);
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow, 0 0 20px rgb(17, 90, 50), 0 0 40px rgb(12, 85, 24), 0 0 80px yellow,
            0 0 120px yellow, 0 0 200px yellow, 0 0 300px yellow, 0 0 400px yellow;
    }

    30%,
    70% {
        color: white;
        filter: blur(2px) hue-rotate(360deg);
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow, 0 0 20px yellow, 0 0 40px yellow, 0 0 80px yellow,
            0 0 120px yellow, 0 0 200px yellow, 0 0 300px yellow, 0 0 400px yellow;
    }

    100% {
        color: transparent;
        box-shadow: none;
        filter: blur(2px) hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
    height: 20rem;
    gap: 5px;
}

.slider div {
    flex: 1;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.25, .4, .45, 1.4);
}

.slider div:hover {
    flex: 5;
}


.contenedor4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 400px;
    align-items: center;
}

.contenedor4 img {

    height: 50px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.text-container {
    background-color: rgb(218, 162, 11);
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    width: 650px;
    border-radius: 25% 10%;
}

.text-container2 {
    background-color: rgb(218, 162, 11);
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    width: 650px;
    border-radius: 25% 10%;
}

.containerT {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilosborrados.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bad+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bacasime+Antique&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bacasime+Antique&family=Libre+Baskerville:ital@1&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Ojeda</title>
</head>

<body style="background-image: url(images1/modern-white-background-free-vector.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: 100% 100%; background-attachment: fixed;">

    <header>
        <nav>
            <img src="images1/logo.png" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="nosotros.html">Quienes somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="portafolio.html">Portafolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicios.html">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="testimonios.html">Testimonios</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="iconosocial">

                <ul>

                    <li><a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <h1>
            <span style="--i:1;">O</span>
            <span style="--i:2;">J</span>
            <span style="--i:3;">E</span>
            <span style="--i:4;">D</span>
            <span style="--i:5;">A</span>
            <span style="--i:6;margin-left: 5vw;">M</span>
            <span style="--i:7;">A</span>
            <span style="--i:8;">R</span>
            <span style="--i:9;">K</span>
            <span style="--i:10;">E</span>
            <span style="--i:11;">T</span>
        </h1>

    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="texto-debajo">
            <p>Un mercado que se dedica a la venta de diversos productos de consumo inmediato y de primera necesidad
                para
                satisfacer la necesidad de los clientes. </p>
            <p> Los proveedores son confiables y se dedican a traer productos de marcas conocidas para garantizar la
                calidad
                de todos los productos y así también vender una gran cantidad de productos. El objetivo de la empresa
            </p>
            <p> es brindar experiencia de compra conveniente y agradable en un ambiente acogedor. Se esfuerza por
                superar
                las expectativas de los clientes y establecer relaciones duraderas basadas en la confianza y la
                satisfacción.</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Portafolio</h3>

    </section>
    <section>
 <div class="slider">
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria1.jpg);">IMAGE</div>
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria2.jpg);">IMAGE</div>
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria3.jpg);">IMAGE</div>
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria4.jpg);">IMAGE</div>
        <div style="background-image: url(images1/galeria5.jpg);">IMAGE</div>
    </div>
    </section>
   

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, en el nav puse z-index: 1 y ahora el nav pasa por encima de todo. Gracias por la ayuda!